# Reusable Vue Components - How to use props to define v-for array and path for unique Axios responses

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm using Vue components for multiple inputs with different axios url's and responses. Then using a v-for loop for the response to be displayed which can be selected.

*idea*:

- Input 1 > Axios GET *user* data
- Input 2 > Axios GET *colour* data
- Input 3 > Axios GET *model* data

etc, each Axios response can have a different response array and objects.

I can set the different Axios GET url's by using props, but how can I use props to define the v-for array path and object path?

example image sample showing needed link between prop and v-for:

[image: Image sample showing needed link between prop and v-for]

Can I use props to define the array path and object in the f-vor loop? In the example code below I need to use the prop from the component to define the array and object paths. *note I'm using a axios sample response for this demo.*

```js
Vue.component("my-component", {
  template: `
<div style="position:absolute"><input :placeholder="this.input_placeholder" @keyup="if(input_value.length > 2 ){ search() }" v-on:blur="input_clear()" v-model="input_value" /><i v-if="loading_spinner" class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i><div class="supplier_select_popup" v-if="response_popup_show"><div v-for="data,i in response_array.bpi" v-on:click="response_select(i)">{{ data.code }}</div></div></div>`,
  props: {
    api_url: "",
    api_response_path: "",
    data_path: "",
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      input_placeholder: "Search",
      input_value: "",
      selected_value: "",
      loading_spinner: false,
      response_popup_show: false,
      response_array: [],
    };
  },

  methods: {
    // Fetch Data
    search: function() {
      this.response_popup_show = false
      this.loading_spinner = true
      clearTimeout(this.myVar)
      this.myVar = setTimeout(
        function() {
          axios
            .get(
              this.api_url
            )
            .then((response) => {
              this.response_array = response.data
              console.log(this.response_array)
              this.response_popup_show = true
              this.loading_spinner = false
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error)
              this.errored = true;
              this.response_popup_show = false
            })
            .finally(() => (this.loading = false))
        }.bind(this),
        1000
      );
    },
    // Response Select
    response_select: function(i) {
      this.input_value = [i]
      this.selected_value = [i]
      this.response_popup_show = false
    },
    // Response Clear
    input_clear: function() {
      var self = this;
      setTimeout(function() {
        self.response_popup_show = false
        self.loading_spinner = false
        if (self.selected_value.length != 0) {
          self.input_value = self.selected_value
        } else {
          self.input_value = ""
        }
      }, 100);
    }
  }
});

const App = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/17cdac82ba.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-component class="clickable" api_url="https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json" api_response_path="response_array.bpi" data_path="date.code">
  </my-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by passing the property you want to use for both the API response and each data item, but I prefer to generalize it by passing "map" functions, that way you aren't limited in any way by how you want to transform the data:

```js
props: [
  'map_response',
  'map_data',
]
```

```vue
<div v-for="data, i in map_response(responseArray)">
  {{ map_data(data) }}
</div>
```

You pass the props like this:

```vue
<my-component
  class="clickable"
  api_url="http://api.example.com/stuff"
  :map_response="response => response.bpi"
  :map_data="data => data.code"
>
```

Comment: Legend! Works as expected, Ive been stumped on this one for ages.